# Atlcoin: Peers don't sync after one creating new block

Tags: altcoin, litecoin, synchronization

I have made an altcoin flowing these steps:
1. Generate genesis block and modify in source code

```
genesis = CreateGenesisBlock(1525404232, 5226643, 0x1e0ffff0, 1, 50 * COIN);
    consensus.hashGenesisBlock = genesis.GetHash();
    assert(consensus.hashGenesisBlock == uint256S("35bd3f056789cdf9b03bda2da62b3051387a91af784314966c6b303e33ec0f0b"));
    assert(genesis.hashMerkleRoot == uint256S("52b2455696516c14fde6fb8bf13891f34a49b339b99aa863942e5cd54db71fc1"));
```

2. Remove checkpoints

   checkpointData = {
           {
               { 0 , uint256S("0x35bd3f056789cdf9b03bda2da62b3051387a91af784314966c6b303e33ec0f0b")}
           }
       };

Now, I run this code in two machines (two nodes) and make them connect to each other with command "addnode ".

After that, I start mining in the first node

```
generatetoaddress 1 <address>
```

After first node create block 1, I check the chain info of the second node

```
getblockcount
```

and it return 0. Any suggestion for me to solve this problems?